# RDP won't span across multiple monitors anymore

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, windows-10

Windows 7: works.

In Windows 8.1: worked perfectly.

In Windows 10 Insider Preview: worked perfectly.

In Windows 10 Pro: Works only on one monitor. Ignores /span and /multimonitor params.

I have absolutely no idea what the hell happened.
Did not run system integrity check though.

Comment: While I know /span should accomplish the same thing, have you tried checking the box in MSTSC to 'User all my monitors for the remote session'?

Comment: @MrStatic sure I did. The RDP program ignores ALL the multimonitor parameters I've set, even commandline params don't work.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you are running? Are you trying an RDP file or from the command line? (RDP file might override the MSTSC settings)

Comment: @cdavid `mstsc /span` works at work and worked at homeoffice until Windows 10 Insider Preview got upgraded to Windows 10 RTM. Even if I check the checkboxes in the GUI to use all of my monitors and the full resolution, It's limited to one monitor. As a workaround I could activate NVidia Surround......